# CSS and JQUERY issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi does anyone know how to make a jquery work inside of a css media query, or when the screen size is smaller than a certain size. I need my nav tag to be toggled shut **but only when my site is in mobile view.** I already have a CSS media query set up that goes into action when the the device is less than 1050px wide.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: have you considered using bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: No I have heard of it but I have already got the whole code for the nav so I would like to stick with this :d

Comment: bootstrap gives you access to some extremely useful classes like `hidden-xs` where the element will not show on screens smaller than 768px or `visible-xs` which only sows on screens smaller than 768px

Comment: How does it work? Would it affect my current navigation?

Comment: take a look at bootstrap when you can, it will change your life :D in the mean time, try this https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/12/

Comment: the menu is hidden when the screen size is < 768px.. so shrink the window down and it will hide the list.. then click "menu" and it will show again

Comment: Do you know how to make a jquery that runs when the screen size is smaller than a certain size?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/14/

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// This will fire when document is ready:
$(window).resize(function() {
    // This will fire each time the window is resized:
    if($(window).width() >= 1050) {
        // if larger or equal
        $('nav').show();
    } else {
        // if smaller
        $('nav').hide();
    }
}).resize(); // This will simulate a resize to trigger the initial run.
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment yet, but in order to stay with your HTML I can offer you something like this:

```
if( $(window).width() < 480) {
    // Put your script in here
}
```

Also take a look at Modernizr. Thou you if you are not familiar with Bootstrap, simple solution like I offered should seal the deal for you. ;)

Comment: Lets me try this please

Comment: Can you paste the script? What I gave is what I am using most of the time as I lazy solution.

Comment: Well, from what I can see from your own answer is that my solution actually works. `resize()` is needed only if you need functionality on desktops too. You should also use some sort of [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) function to trigger `resize()` only once on window size change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<style>

header{
  width:100%;
  background:black;
}

ul{
list-style:none;
}

li{
float:left;
}

a{
display:block;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
color:orange;
}
</style>

<body>
<header>
  <div class="Menu_bar">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Hme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
        <div class="clearFix"></div>
     </ul>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
```